# Get status bar text

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, statusbar

I am trying to retrieve the text from my programs status bar so that I can use it during wm_drawitem event. The following code returns a zero value for statustext instead of the first panes text.

```
char statusText[1024];

int nLength = SendMessage(hStatus, SB_GETTEXTLENGTH, (WPARAM)0, 0);
int len = SendMessage (hStatus, SB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)statusText);
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

The status bar is set up like this:

```
int parts[3] = { 100, 408, 508};
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETPARTS, 3, (LPARAM)&parts);
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, SBT_OWNERDRAW|SBT_NOBORDERS|0, (LPARAM)"Ready");
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, SBT_OWNERDRAW|SBT_NOBORDERS|1, (LPARAM)NULL);
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, SBT_OWNERDRAW|SBT_NOBORDERS|2, (LPARAM)timeStr); 
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETBKCOLOR , 0, (LPARAM)RGB(219,227,250));
```

Comment: That looks ok on the face of it. What does SB_GETTEXTLENGTH return? Are you sure it's really part #0 you want? Are you sure it's not ownerdraw?

Comment: I do not know what SB_GETTEXTLENGTH is returning. I am pretty sure part #0 is what I want although I have tried all 3 parts. Yes it is ownerdrawn. Does ownerdraw affect the SB_GETTEXT somehow?

Comment: If it's owner-drawn then it doesn't necessarily have text you can get.

Comment: Since it's your program, why don't you just get the status text from the program (e.g., the variable itself), rather than ask Windows for the text?